Не работает CustomActivity. / CustomActivity is not working
При запуске программы ошибок никаких нет но и статуса тоже нету. Если использовать стандартные Activity То всё работает.
`@Sony.event
async def on_ready():
    Sony.loop.create_task(status_task())
    Sony.loop.create_task(rndm())
async def status_task():
    while True:
        await Sony.change_presence ( activity = disnake.CustomActivity(name = random.choice(status_task)))
        await asyncio.sleep (100)`

вот как выглядит код
Я испробовал все возможные методы перестановок и подстановок, но результата так и не добился
